# Flash Linksys Router with TomatoVPN

Tags: firmware, tomato

Can anyone point me, or help me in the update of Linksys with TomatoVPN?

I'm running Tomato firmware; however, when I visit http://tomatoVPN.keithmoyer.com/ I don't see where I can download the firmware update as 7zip file? They mention to download the update as 7zip file: https://www.VPNtunnel.se/howto/openVPN-tomato.PDF but I cannot see the files on the site, or am I missing a process here that I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link for the latest version on that page is under the text "You can download the binaries from [here](http://tomatovpn.tomatomod.de/release/1.27vpn3.6/)."

I have used that tomato mod and had very good success. But, I would suggest the following alternative, as it is slightly more up to date, with some nice additional features. -> [TomatoUSB](http://tomatousb.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I followed the link on his page to the forum and the forum listed the download here http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato.  There is a 7z file available.  Take a look